# Visual Studio: Doc Comments that get updated when renaming classes/fields/methods

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, renaming, xml-comments

I have a class (written in C#) with some documentation comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract class defining a tolerance-based method for Equals.
/// Tolerance must be defined in a derived class like this:
/// <code>class MyPrec : Precision { private MyPrec() : base(42) {} }</code>
/// (This subclass will have a tolerance of 42.)
/// </summary>
public abstract class Precision
{
    protected readonly double TOL;

    protected Precision(double tol)
    {
        TOL = tol;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if two doubles are equal up to numerical tolerance given by TOL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">First double.</param>
    /// <param name="right">Second double.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the absolute value of the difference is at most TOL,
    ///          false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool Equals(double left, double right)
    {
        return Math.Abs(left - right) <= TOL;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not Equals.
    /// </summary>
    public bool NotEquals(double left, double right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

If I rename the parameter `left` in the `Equals` method via Visual Studio's renaming feature, it automatically gets renamed in the documentation comment, too. But it seems that this only works for immediate parameters.

How do I write the documentation comments such that the following words are also updated by Visual Studio when renaming the corresponding class/field/method?

- `Precision` in the code example of the summary comment of the class `Precision`

  ```
      /// <code>class MyPrec : Precision { private MyPrec() : base(42) {} }</code>
  ```
- `TOL` in the return comment of the method `Equals`

  ```
  /// <returns>True if the absolute value of the difference is at most TOL,
  ```
- `Equals` in the summary comment of `NotEquals`

  ```
  /// Not Equals.
  ```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

I already tried

```
    /// <returns>True if the absolute value of the difference is at most <paramref name="TOL"/>,
```

but it does not work. It is no input paramter after all.

Comment: Please post your related question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Precision, I think this is not possible. The comment inside the <code> tag is a free text.
- For TOL and Equals, this is simple. Use the [<see>](http://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/aseelinkxml.htm) tag when you refer to another code member in your comments. Renaming will be applied to such elements. In your case the comment will be:

  ```
  /// <returns>True if the absolute value of the difference is at most <see cref="TOL"/>,
  ```

and

```
    /// Not <see cref="Equals"/>.
```